# Fi score -Sklearn

Tags: precision, precision-recall

What is the F1-score of the model in the following? I used scikit learn package.

```
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
              precision    recall  f1-score   support
<BLANKLINE>
     class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
     class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
     class 2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3
<BLANKLINE>
    accuracy                           0.60         5
   macro avg       0.50      0.56      0.49         5
weighted avg       0.70      0.60      0.61         5
```

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/accuracy-precision-recall-or-f1-331fb37c5cb9)  explains it pretty well

Basically it's

`F1 = 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall)`

Comment: Thank you @ksooklall My problem is what value i need to use as f1 score in the output i listed above? (macro avg or weighted avg ) 0.49 or 0.61

Comment: I would say you want `micro:
Calculate metrics globally by counting the total true positives, false negatives and false positives.`

Comment: if that correctly answers your question please accept the solution so this question can be closed